# Using QHttpMultiPart with PUT operation and form fields

Tags: c++, qt, cloudflare, cloudflare-workers

I'm having quite a bit of struggle in trying to achieve a simple PUT request in QT. Frankly I am still a starter using this framework so I have much left to learn.

What I am trying to do is make a PUT request with 2 parameters this [Cloudflare Workers KV API](https://api.cloudflare.com/#workers-kv-namespace-write-key-value-pair-with-metadata).

With that being said this is my current code snippet:

```
QString szUrl = "";

QHttpMultiPart* multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QHttpPart valuePart;
valuePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"value\""));
valuePart.setBody(value.toByteArray());

QHttpPart metadataPart;
metadataPart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"metadata\""));
metadataPart.setBody(metadata.toByteArray());

multiPart->append(valuePart);
multiPart->append(metadataPart);

QNetworkRequest request;

request.setUrl(szUrl);
request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "multipart/form-data");
request.setRawHeader("Authorization", QString("Bearer %1").arg("...").toUtf8());

QNetworkReply* reply = m_NetworkManager->put(request, multiPart);

// delete the multiPart with the reply
multiPart->setParent(reply);

// Process reply (QNetworkAccessManager::finished)
// Process errors (QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors)

qDebug() << reply->error();
qDebug() << reply->readAll();
qDebug() << reply->errorString();
```

The above returns always HTTP 400 (bad request) with zero, and I mean ZERO response. I could not retrieve the error response from the API in any way. Just an empty string ("") under debug.

If I execute the example cURL cli code from the API page, it works perfectly. I get a response and it's successful.

My question would be, what on earth am I doing wrong? I read the documentation and wrote the code accordingly, I cannot understand what's happening.

I have searched quite a bit for a possible answer online but unfortunately all issues and examples are with POST requests and file uploads (mostly).

Please advise, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer my own question because one of the reasons the above was not working it's because of my own fault.

**Problem 1:**

Bad formatting of metadata. Looks like Cloudflare API wants the metadata "compressed".

**Problem 2:**

Unable to retrieve API error response. Now this is an interesting one because I found countless forum posts and posts even here with the same problem, yet nobody posted the actual solution.

The [readAll()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qiodevice.html#readAll) function states this issue:

> This function has no way of reporting errors; returning an empty
> QByteArray can mean either that no data was currently available for
> reading, **or that an error occurred**. This function also has no way of
> indicating that more data may have been available and couldn't be
> read.

The resolution is to connect QIODevice::readyRead to as per the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkaccessmanager.html#details):

```
connect(reply, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, [=]() {
    QByteArray response = reply->readAll();
    qDebug() << response;
});
```

You now have the server reply regardless of the HTTP error code.

With that being said 2 problems solved in one go, enjoy.